# Does dynamic import work with variable , or it requires hard coded string?

Tags: angular

1.) The code works normal if ,

```
    export async function demoT(){
      var a= await import('plugins/user-admin-plugin.bundle.js');
    }
```

2.) But it is not able to resolve the bundle when ,

```
    export async function demoT(){
      var path='plugins/user-admin-plugin.bundle.js';
      var a= await import(path);
    }
```

Comment: Appears like you answered your own question

Comment: i know it works with hard coded string , but is it necessary always to put a hard coded string?